# How to create new object in ArrayList with every new arguments

Tags: java, arraylist

public class AlarmsFragment extends Fragment {

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView checkText;
ArrayList<AlarmObjects> alarmObjects;


public AlarmsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarms, container, false);

    floatingActionButton = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_button);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_alarms);

     alarmObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(getContext(),alarmObjects);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    if (arguments != null){
       String newTime = getArguments().getString("newTimm");
        String newNotes = getArguments().getString("newNott");
        checkText.setText(newTime + newNotes);
        alarmObjects.add(new AlarmObjects(newNotes,newTime));
       }

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showPopupmeth();
        }
    });


    return  v;

    }

   }
```

it keeps updating same object it created but doesnt create new one can you help i am new to this.

```
  public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, int id) {
    changeTitle(id);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

using this method i come back to my alarmsFragment. When i come back to it from dialog fragment it creates new ArrayList every time as i understood. How can i make it show existing objects and add new ones using getArguments

Comment: Is this code in side a loop.

Comment: Hmm, first you add alarmObjects list to alarmAdapter and then you add elements to that list

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I cannot get what you want to do.

You initialize an ArrayList here:

```
alarmObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

And put the first object into the array here:

```
 alarmObjects.add(new AlarmObjects(newNotes,newTime)); }
```

What behaviour do you expect?

EDIT:

try this:

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView checkText;
ArrayList<AlarmObjects> alarmObjects = new ArrayList<>();

public AlarmsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarms, container, false);

    floatingActionButton = v.findViewById(R.id.fab_button);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_alarms);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(getContext(),alarmObjects);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    if (arguments != null){
       String newTime = getArguments().getString("newTimm");
        String newNotes = getArguments().getString("newNott");
        checkText.setText(newTime + newNotes);
        alarmObjects.add(new AlarmObjects(newNotes,newTime));
       }

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showPopupmeth();
        }
    });


    return  v;
    enter code here
    }

   }
```

Comment: When i restart the fragment i want to add new object i get two strings from dialog fragment. This code just updates existing object doesnt create new one

Comment: What do you mean by restart fragment . Add the complete method which runs when you want to add new Object. Mostly, you might be creating new ArrayList everytime you call the method which gives you effect like you are updating same object but instead it is creating new ArrayList everytime.

Comment: AlarmsFragment alarmsFragment = new AlarmsFragment();
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle.putString("newTimm",times);
                   bundle.putString("newNott", notes);
                   alarmsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragment(alarmsFragment, R.string.alarm_string);
                   dismiss(); this is from my dialog fragment

Comment: @Shoha
When you perform
    alarmObjects = new ArrayList<>();
you are re-initializing the object alarmObjects . You are creating a new, empty, arraylist object. If you don't want that, you have to remove this instruction.

Comment: Do I take it out of scope? I need to have at least 1 Arraylist right? where do i declare it so it gets executed only 1 time? @rocky

Comment: As already said by @thought4J, in the portion of code that you posted, you are creating a new arraylist every time, loosing what you add before. You should avoid to create a new arraylist every time the method is called if you want to mantain the previous elements of the list.
One solution is to declare the arraylist outside that portion of code, and the pass it as reference of that method.

Comment: Nullpointer means that you have not initialized your array with a new().
Do it, not inside that portion of code, but before, in a place that is not called every time.

Comment: Can you have a look now please i added the rest

Comment: The line ArrayList<AlarmObjects> alarmObjects; (line number 4) -- change this to ArrayList<AlarmObjects> alarmObjects = new ArrayList<>(); and remove the new array list creation inside the method. this should solve your problem

Comment: Nope didnt help still have only one object in recyclerview. It just updates the string or creates new List everytime.

Comment: Just a small suggestion. This use case is a basic concept of Java, and generally speaking of the Object Oriented languages. I suggest to you to learn these fundamentals, before applying them in a "complex" context.
Objects life cycle, array initiallization, local and global variables, variable by reference. These are some topics that you should have yours before code anything.

Comment: I agree ı spent little time on fundamentals. But I think it should be easy for you to solve since you are an experienced programmer. Thats why i came here the first place to find my mistakes. and i mentioned that i am new to this and experience comes with practice

Comment: @thought4J told this 21 minutes ago tried same result

Comment: The behaviour can has a lot of reasons. Where and when the class you posted is initialized? How it's used?
The solution proposed, create an array at the beginning and then add the objects is THE WAY.
HOW to implement it, it depends on your application, how you use your class.

Comment: Can you show me  how to use values taken from Dialog Fragment and use it to create a new object in ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

This is only a part of the code. I assume the code above is being called for every new arguments. If so, then the following is what is happening:
On the first line you are doing new ArrayList() which always creates a new (and empty) array list. 
On the last line you are adding a new AlarmObjects to the list. 
So, when you try to retrieve the element from the list you get the most recently added element. This is why you are thinking it is modifying the existing element. 
In reality, you are adding a new element. But you are also recreating the list every time. So you are not seeing the previous element

Instead of creating a new arraylist every time, create one in the parent method and pass the reference to this method.

```
public void parentMethod(){
    List<AlarmObjects> alarmObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    childMethod(alarmObjects);
}
public void childMethod(List<AlarmObjects> alarmObjects){
    //all of your code except the new ArrayList<>() goes here
}
```

Comment: It is only a part of the code you have posted. So I cannot give the exact solution. Is this piece of code inside a method? I have given a pseudo code assuming this piece of code is in a child method and there is a parent method calling this.

Comment: I have to call both when I start fragment for the first time. and after ı take string from dialog fragment i make transaction to this fragment again and both of them get executed again

Answer (score 0):

Your is only part in and not clear enough, So I am assuming that you want create Immutable ArrayList,You can implement it as follows by using unmodifiableList method of Collections framework Java 8

i.e Collections unmodifiableList(list);

Example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
unmodifiableList.add("four");
```